# Custom rule against input array in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a custom rule against an array of checkboxes. The request data comes in properly like

```
cbarray => [
  cb1 => null,
  cb2 => true,
  cb3 => true,
]
```

I'm trying to make a validation rule that fails if all the checkboxes are set to true.

Then I've added it to my laravel rules as

`'job-payment.*' => [ new NotAllTrue ],`

expecting that this would be sent into my rule as an array of values, but it appears to only send in the first attribute and value.

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class NotAllTrue implements Rule
{    
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return !array_reduce($value, function ($carry, $val) {
            return $carry && $val;
        }, true);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'These cannot all be true.';
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you don't add the `.*` to the rule?

Comment: That was it, thanks @Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the whole array you have to write this way:

```
'job-payment' => [ new NotAllTrue ],
```

If you want to independently validate each element of the array then:

```
'job-payment.*' => [ new NotAllTrue ],
```